# Can I speed up File Sync for Ubuntu One?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I am using ubuntu 11.04 on my home laptop and the same on my work laptop. I just wanted to sync the work folders on my home laptop to my office laptop which is ~300Mb of data. This would normally be a short download but ubuntu-one is taking forever to sync it. Any ideas what could cause this? I am not behind any firewall or anything of that sort. I have not checked the limit bandwidth box in the preferences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer is No!, I am afraid, apart from the obvious, adsl speeds, etc.

I am having the same issue. I have been trying to sync my documents folder of 1.4GB, it still hasn't worked and it has been syncing for a month. The top level syncs, files and folders in the Document folders, but contents of sub-folders just hang.

I have tried using the backup facility in 11.10, to backup to Ubuntu One.... I upgraded my HDD space in Ubuntu One. It has been going now for 24hours and only backed up what looks like a couple of percent.

The odd thing is I can sync to drop box within hours, rather than months.

This is bad, and has been an issue since Ubuntu One's release. I have reported this problem and there were promises in later releases this would be fixed, but it hasn't.

Canonical cannot help either...

So my advice is to use dropbox or another service, until it is sorted, but as Ubuntu does not seem to see this as an issue, I think a fix will be a long time in coming.

Yes my internet speeds are fine, etc... :-)

Thanks